# Error passing mysql connection as parameter

Tags: php, mysql, api

I'm trying to build a basic API with PHP and mysql and depending on the url path, different database tables are used and therefore the connection needs to be made. But I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
>   in....line 6

dashboard.class.php:

```
class dashboard {
    public function getData($conn) {
        // Get latest status
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT status FROM status_archive ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1 ");
        $stmt->execute(); //line 6
        $stmt->bind_result($status);
        $stmt->fetch();
        ($status == '1' ? $status = 'up' : $status = 'down');
        $stmt->close();
        return $status;
    }
}
```

Function that creates the database connection:

```
function db_connection($type) {
   $db = $type.'_db';
   syslog(LOG_INFO, 'DB: '.$db);
   // Check to see if a development or production server is being used
   if (strpos(getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE'), 'Development') === false) {
      $conn = mysqli_connect(null,
                              getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME'),
                              getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD'),
                              $db,
                              null,
                              getenv('PRODUCTION_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE'));
   } else {
      $conn = mysqli_connect(getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST'), 
                              getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_USERNAME'),
                              getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD'),
                              $db);
   }
   // Check if successful connection to database
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Could not connect to database: $conn->connect_error " .
         "[$conn->connect_errno]");
   }

   return $conn;
}
```

This is the code at the end of the file that initiates everything:

```
$path_array = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH));
$conn = db_connection($path_array[3]);
include 'classes/dashboard.class.php';
$dashboard = new dashboard;
$results = $dashboard->getData($conn);
echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: smells like variable scope to me

Comment: Check for errors. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code (query and all).

Comment: Have you tried `new mysqli` instead of `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: var_dump($conn). Check to see what $conn actually is.  You should add code that ensures $conn is an instance of PDO/MySQLi/whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was due to variable scope.

I ended up using PHP $GLOBALS to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_connect` can to return falsy value.
You should use OOP style (`new mysqli`) or check `$conn`:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$conn) {
    die('Connection error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

[php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) - See "Procedural style" example.